# Leaky Windows caused drywall discoloration / damage - how to approach repair?

Tags: drywall, repair, windows, leak, caulking

After a heavy rainfall I noticed that an area of the drywall was discolored and cold/soft and managed to push it in (woops). This area is usually behind a curtain so we never noticed it before. I checked outside and noticed the caulking on the side (see image 2) has some cracks so I will remove/recaulk that, but I have no clue what to do to repair the pushed in drywall/discoloration. The discolored area is maybe the size of my fist and the pushed in area is maybe just over 1cm (size of my fingernail), but it feels slightly soft/cold around it. Do I just patch this? Or do I need to replace the drywall around the windowsill?

Also, I noticed some cracks between the window and the windowsill/wall on the interior (images 4&5) and want to patch those. Do I just use caulk?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Get some professional help.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest getting some professional help, I believe there is much more involved than a simple patch. You have water leaking into the wall causing mold to grow. They will probably remove more of the drywall and find a much larger area that has been damaged. They need to find where the water is coming in, probably the window but not for sure. At that point they can repair it properly.

Comment: What sort of professional would I call? Drywall contractor? The water is definitely coming in from the window there are cracks in the caulk. That I can do myself, but who should I ask to come in for the drywall repair?

Comment: I am not sure, I have my favorites but they are not in your area. Start with somebody that can do remediation on the mold, that may be a drywall contractor. There are other companies that clean up after flooding etc it may be smart to contact them. Your insurance may cover this, just guessing. If you want to replace the window then a window contractor.